# Не могу привести строку к валидному json (C#)

Tags: c#, json

У меня есть json ответ от сайта, но этот json очень специфически форматирован: все кавычки и слеши прописаны через слеш-кавычку и двойные слеши, как будто в коде C#. Я пытался заменить все слеш-символы оригинальными, но тогда пропадают некоторые лишний слеш-символы в атрибуте `data` и json не парсится.

Как я пытался сделать:

```
// метод расширения
public static async Task<string> GetContent(this HttpClient httpClient, string url)
{
    if (url is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url));

    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return content;
}
```

```
var content = await httpClient.GetContent("https://nz.ua/ru/dashboard/getnextnews");
content     = content.Replace(@"\\", "");
content     = content.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
content     = content.Remove(0, 1);
content     = content.Remove(content.Length - 1, 1);

var json = JObject.Parse(content);
```

Фактическое содержание content: https://justpaste.it/76tqq

Оригинальный ответ сервера:

```
"{\"lastNews\":\"177286396\",\"newsId\":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],\"data\":\"    <li>\\n        <div class=\\\"clear\\\">\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-author\\\"><a \\n                    href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id3439774\\\" \\n                    title=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a \\u042e\\u043b\\u0456\\u044f \\u041b\\u0435\\u043e\\u043d\\u0456\\u0434\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\" class=\\\"mla-image\\\"><img \\n                        src=\\\"\\/users_img\\/users\\/avatars\\/343\\/3439774\\/20x20.jpg\\\" \\n                        alt=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a \\u042e\\u043b\\u0456\\u044f \\u041b\\u0435\\u043e\\u043d\\u0456\\u0434\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\" \\n                        height=\\\"20\\\" width=\\\"20\\\" \\/><\\/a> \\n                    <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id3439774\\\" \\n                       title=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a \\u042e\\u043b\\u0456\\u044f \\u041b\\u0435\\u043e\\u043d\\u0456\\u0434\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\">\\n                          <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id3439774\\\">\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a \\u042e\\u043b\\u0456\\u044f \\u041b\\u0435\\u043e\\u043d\\u0456\\u0434\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430<\\/a><\\/a>\\n            <\\/div>\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-date\\\">56 \\u043c\\u0438\\u043d. \\u043d\\u0430\\u0437\\u0430\\u0434<\\/div>\\n        <\\/div>\\n\\n                        <div class=\\\"ml-message\\\">\\n                    \\u0412\\u044b \\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u0443\\u0447\\u0438\\u043b\\u0438 \\u043e\\u0446\\u0435\\u043d\\u043a\\u0443 10 \\u043f\\u043e \\u043f\\u0440\\u0435\\u0434\\u043c\\u0435\\u0442\\u0443: \\u0423\\u043a\\u0440\\u0430\\u0457\\u043d\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430 \\u043c\\u043e\\u0432\\u0430 , \\u041a\\u043e\\u043d\\u0442\\u0440\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0430 \\u0440\\u043e\\u0431\\u043e\\u0442\\u0430                <\\/div>\\n                    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        <div class=\\\"clear\\\">\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-author\\\"><a \\n                    href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id3447069\\\" \\n                    title=\\\"\\u041a\\u0443\\u0437\\u044c\\u043c\\u0438\\u0447\\u043e\\u0432 \\u0406\\u0433\\u043e\\u0440 \\u0406\\u0433\\u043e\\u0440\\u043e\\u0432\\u0438\\u0447\\\" class=\\\"mla-image\\\"><img \\n                        src=\\\"\\/images\\/no_avatar\\/boy.jpg\\\" \\n                        alt=\\\"\\u041a\\u0443\\u0437\\u044c\\u043c\\u0438\\u0447\\u043e\\u0432 \\u0406\\u0433\\u043e\\u0440 \\u0406\\u0433\\u043e\\u0440\\u043e\\u0432\\u0438\\u0447\\\" \\n                        height=\\\"20\\\" width=\\\"20\\\" \\/><\\/a> \\n                    <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id3447069\\\" \\n                       title=\\\"\\u041a\\u0443\\u0437\\u044c\\u043c\\u0438\\u0447\\u043e\\u0432 \\u0406\\u0433\\u043e\\u0440 \\u0406\\u0433\\u043e\\u0440\\u043e\\u0432\\u0438\\u0447\\\">\\n                          <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id3447069\\\">\\u041a\\u0443\\u0437\\u044c\\u043c\\u0438\\u0447\\u043e\\u0432 \\u0406\\u0433\\u043e\\u0440 \\u0406\\u0433\\u043e\\u0440\\u043e\\u0432\\u0438\\u0447<\\/a><\\/a>\\n            <\\/div>\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-date\\\">\\u0441\\u0435\\u0433\\u043e\\u0434\\u043d\\u044f \\u0432 20:32<\\/div>\\n        <\\/div>\\n\\n                        <div class=\\\"ml-message\\\">\\n                    <b>\\u041d\\u043e\\u0432\\u043e\\u0441\\u0442\\u044c \\u0438\\u0437 \\u0441\\u043e\\u043e\\u0431\\u0449\\u0435\\u0441\\u0442\\u0432\\u0430: \\u041c\\u043e\\u0439 \\u043a\\u043b\\u0430\\u0441\\u0441<\\/b><br>\\u0410\\u043d\\u0443, \\u0442\\u0435\\u0441\\u0442 \\u0442\\u0430\\u043a\\u043e\\u0439 \\u0432\\u043e\\u0442<br>\\u043b\\u044f\\u043b\\u044f\\u043b\\u044f\\u043b\\u044f\\u043b\\u044f...<br><a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/comm34577\\/news\\/14963\\\">\\u041f\\u043e\\u0434\\u0440\\u043e\\u0431\\u043d\\u0435\\u0435<\\/a><a class=\\\"pull-right user-list-show\\\" href=\\\"\\/ru\\/comm34577\\/news\\/14963\\\">\\u041a\\u0442\\u043e \\u043f\\u043e\\u0441\\u043c\\u043e\\u0442\\u0440\\u0435\\u043b \\u043d\\u043e\\u0432\\u043e\\u0441\\u0442\\u044c<\\/a>                <\\/div>\\n                                    <div class=\\\"user-list-popup\\\">\\n                                                    <ul class=\\\"list-group\\\">\\n                                    <li>\\n        \\u0410\\u043d\\u0434\\u0440\\u0456\\u0454\\u0432\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0438\\u0439 \\u0410\\u043d\\u0434\\u0440\\u0456\\u0439        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n                    <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u0411\\u0430\\u0445\\u0456\\u0440\\u043a\\u043e \\u0414\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438\\u043b\\u043e        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n         \\n            <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u0413\\u043e\\u0433\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c \\u0412\\u0430\\u043b\\u0435\\u0440\\u0456\\u044f        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n         \\n            <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u0404\\u0441\\u0438\\u043f\\u0435\\u043d\\u043a\\u043e \\u0412\\u0430\\u0441\\u0438\\u043b\\u044c        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n         \\n            <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u0416\\u043e\\u043b\\u0443\\u0434\\u044c \\u0412\\u0456\\u043a\\u0442\\u043e\\u0440\\u0456\\u044f        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n         \\n            <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u0406\\u0432\\u0430\\u0441\\u0438\\u043d\\u0430 \\u0412\\u0456\\u043a\\u0442\\u043e\\u0440\\u0456\\u044f        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n                    <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u041a\\u043e\\u0447\\u0435\\u0433\\u0430\\u0440\\u043e\\u0432\\u0430 \\u0412\\u0430\\u043b\\u0435\\u0440\\u0456\\u044f        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n                    <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u041a\\u0440\\u0443\\u0433\\u043b\\u0430 \\u0415\\u043b\\u0456\\u043d\\u0430        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n         \\n            <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u041a\\u0443\\u0437\\u044c\\u043c\\u0438\\u0447\\u043e\\u0432 \\u0406\\u0433\\u043e\\u0440        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n         \\n            <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u041b\\u043e\\u0436\\u043d\\u0456\\u043a\\u043e\\u0432\\u0430 \\u0414\\u0430\\u0440'\\u044f        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n                    <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u041c\\u0435\\u0440\\u043a\\u0443\\u043b\\u043e\\u0432 \\u0414\\u043c\\u0438\\u0442\\u0440\\u043e        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n                    <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u041c\\u0438\\u0445\\u0430\\u0439\\u043b\\u0438\\u043a \\u042e\\u0440\\u0456\\u0439        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n                    <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u041c\\u043e\\u0432\\u0447\\u0430\\u043d \\u0410\\u043d\\u0430\\u0441\\u0442\\u0430\\u0441\\u0456\\u044f        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n         \\n            <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u041c\\u0443\\u0445\\u0430 \\u0412\\u0456\\u043a\\u0442\\u043e\\u0440        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n         \\n            <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u041d\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u043f\\u0430 \\u0414\\u0435\\u043d\\u0438\\u0441        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n                    <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u041d\\u0435\\u0448\\u0442\\u0443\\u043d \\u0404\\u0433\\u043e\\u0440        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n         \\n            <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u0420\\u0430\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u043e \\u0412\\u0456\\u0442\\u0430\\u043b\\u0456\\u043d\\u0430        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n                    <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u0422\\u0435\\u0433\\u0456\\u043c\\u0431\\u0430\\u0454\\u0432\\u0430 \\u0413\\u0430\\u043d\\u043d\\u0430        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n         \\n            <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u0423\\u0441\\u043e\\u0432\\u0430 \\u0414\\u0430\\u0440'\\u044f        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n                    <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u0427\\u0443\\u0433\\u0443\\u043d\\u043e\\u0432\\u0430 \\u0410\\u043d\\u0430\\u0441\\u0442\\u0430\\u0441\\u0456\\u044f        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n                    <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u0428\\u0432\\u0438\\u0434\\u0435\\u043d\\u043a\\u043e \\u0410\\u043b\\u0456\\u043d\\u0430        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n         \\n            <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u0428\\u0435\\u043b\\u0443\\u0434\\u044c\\u043a\\u043e \\u041d\\u0456\\u043a\\u0456\\u0442\\u0430        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n                    <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        \\u0428\\u043e\\u043a\\u0430\\u0440\\u0435\\u0432\\u0430 \\u041c\\u0430\\u0440\\u0456\\u044f        <span class=\\\"pull-right\\\">\\n                    <i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\\\"><\\/i>\\n                <\\/span>\\n    <\\/li>\\n                            <\\/ul>\\n                                            <\\/div>\\n                    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        <div class=\\\"clear\\\">\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-author\\\"><a \\n                    href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id1536459\\\" \\n                    title=\\\"\\u0413\\u0440\\u0438\\u0433\\u043e\\u0440\\u0435\\u043d\\u043a\\u043e \\u042f\\u043d\\u0456\\u043d\\u0430 \\u0412\\u0456\\u043a\\u0442\\u043e\\u0440\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\" class=\\\"mla-image\\\"><img \\n                        src=\\\"\\/images\\/no_avatar\\/woman.jpg\\\" \\n                        alt=\\\"\\u0413\\u0440\\u0438\\u0433\\u043e\\u0440\\u0435\\u043d\\u043a\\u043e \\u042f\\u043d\\u0456\\u043d\\u0430 \\u0412\\u0456\\u043a\\u0442\\u043e\\u0440\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\" \\n                        height=\\\"20\\\" width=\\\"20\\\" \\/><\\/a> \\n                    <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id1536459\\\" \\n                       title=\\\"\\u0413\\u0440\\u0438\\u0433\\u043e\\u0440\\u0435\\u043d\\u043a\\u043e \\u042f\\u043d\\u0456\\u043d\\u0430 \\u0412\\u0456\\u043a\\u0442\\u043e\\u0440\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\">\\n                          <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id1536459\\\">\\u0413\\u0440\\u0438\\u0433\\u043e\\u0440\\u0435\\u043d\\u043a\\u043e \\u042f\\u043d\\u0456\\u043d\\u0430 \\u0412\\u0456\\u043a\\u0442\\u043e\\u0440\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430<\\/a><\\/a>\\n            <\\/div>\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-date\\\">\\u0441\\u0435\\u0433\\u043e\\u0434\\u043d\\u044f \\u0432 17:22<\\/div>\\n        <\\/div>\\n\\n                        <div class=\\\"ml-message\\\">\\n                    \\u0412\\u044b\\u0434\\u0430\\u043d\\u043e \\u0434\\u0438\\u0441\\u0442\\u0430\\u043d\\u0446\\u0438\\u043e\\u043d\\u043d\\u043e\\u0435 \\u0437\\u0430\\u0434\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435 \\u043f\\u043e \\u043f\\u0440\\u0435\\u0434\\u043c\\u0435\\u0442\\u0443: \\u0425\\u0456\\u043c\\u0456\\u044f                <\\/div>\\n                    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        <div class=\\\"clear\\\">\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-author\\\"><a \\n                    href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id1536454\\\" \\n                    title=\\\"\\u041d\\u0435\\u0448\\u0442\\u0443\\u043d \\u041e\\u043b\\u0435\\u0441\\u044f \\u0412\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u043c\\u0438\\u0440\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\" class=\\\"mla-image\\\"><img \\n                        src=\\\"\\/users_img\\/users\\/avatars\\/153\\/1536454\\/20x20.jpg\\\" \\n                        alt=\\\"\\u041d\\u0435\\u0448\\u0442\\u0443\\u043d \\u041e\\u043b\\u0435\\u0441\\u044f \\u0412\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u043c\\u0438\\u0440\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\" \\n                        height=\\\"20\\\" width=\\\"20\\\" \\/><\\/a> \\n                    <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id1536454\\\" \\n                       title=\\\"\\u041d\\u0435\\u0448\\u0442\\u0443\\u043d \\u041e\\u043b\\u0435\\u0441\\u044f \\u0412\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u043c\\u0438\\u0440\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\">\\n                          <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id1536454\\\">\\u041d\\u0435\\u0448\\u0442\\u0443\\u043d \\u041e\\u043b\\u0435\\u0441\\u044f \\u0412\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u043c\\u0438\\u0440\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430<\\/a><\\/a>\\n            <\\/div>\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-date\\\">\\u0441\\u0435\\u0433\\u043e\\u0434\\u043d\\u044f \\u0432 11:34<\\/div>\\n        <\\/div>\\n\\n                        <div class=\\\"ml-message\\\">\\n                    \\u0412\\u044b \\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u0443\\u0447\\u0438\\u043b\\u0438 \\u043e\\u0446\\u0435\\u043d\\u043a\\u0443 12 \\u043f\\u043e \\u043f\\u0440\\u0435\\u0434\\u043c\\u0435\\u0442\\u0443: \\u0406\\u043d\\u0444\\u043e\\u0440\\u043c\\u0430\\u0442\\u0438\\u043a\\u0430, \\u041f\\u043e\\u0442\\u043e\\u0447\\u043d\\u0430                <\\/div>\\n                    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        <div class=\\\"clear\\\">\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-author\\\"><a \\n                    href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id6523385\\\" \\n                    title=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0442\\u043e\\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430 \\u0417\\u041e\\u0428 I-III \\u0441\\u0442\\u0443\\u043f\\u0435\\u043d\\u0456\\u0432  \\u2116 15 \\u041c\\u041c\\u0420 \\u0417\\u041e  \\\" class=\\\"mla-image\\\"><img \\n                        src=\\\"\\/images\\/no_picture.png\\\" \\n                        alt=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0442\\u043e\\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430 \\u0417\\u041e\\u0428 I-III \\u0441\\u0442\\u0443\\u043f\\u0435\\u043d\\u0456\\u0432  \\u2116 15 \\u041c\\u041c\\u0420 \\u0417\\u041e  \\\" \\n                        height=\\\"20\\\" width=\\\"20\\\" \\/><\\/a> \\n                    <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id6523385\\\" \\n                       title=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0442\\u043e\\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430 \\u0417\\u041e\\u0428 I-III \\u0441\\u0442\\u0443\\u043f\\u0435\\u043d\\u0456\\u0432  \\u2116 15 \\u041c\\u041c\\u0420 \\u0417\\u041e  \\\">\\n                          <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id6523385\\\">\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0442\\u043e\\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430 \\u0417\\u041e\\u0428 I-III \\u0441\\u0442\\u0443\\u043f\\u0435\\u043d\\u0456\\u0432  \\u2116 15 \\u041c\\u041c\\u0420 \\u0417\\u041e  <\\/a><\\/a>\\n            <\\/div>\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-date\\\">\\u0441\\u0435\\u0433\\u043e\\u0434\\u043d\\u044f \\u0432 9:22<\\/div>\\n        <\\/div>\\n\\n                        <div class=\\\"ml-message\\\">\\n                    \\u0412\\u044b\\u0434\\u0430\\u043d\\u043e \\u0434\\u0438\\u0441\\u0442\\u0430\\u043d\\u0446\\u0438\\u043e\\u043d\\u043d\\u043e\\u0435 \\u0437\\u0430\\u0434\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435 \\u043f\\u043e \\u043f\\u0440\\u0435\\u0434\\u043c\\u0435\\u0442\\u0443: \\u0406\\u0441\\u0442\\u043e\\u0440\\u0456\\u044f \\u0423\\u043a\\u0440\\u0430\\u0457\\u043d\\u0438                <\\/div>\\n                    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        <div class=\\\"clear\\\">\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-author\\\"><a \\n                    href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id6523385\\\" \\n                    title=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0442\\u043e\\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430 \\u0417\\u041e\\u0428 I-III \\u0441\\u0442\\u0443\\u043f\\u0435\\u043d\\u0456\\u0432  \\u2116 15 \\u041c\\u041c\\u0420 \\u0417\\u041e  \\\" class=\\\"mla-image\\\"><img \\n                        src=\\\"\\/images\\/no_picture.png\\\" \\n                        alt=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0442\\u043e\\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430 \\u0417\\u041e\\u0428 I-III \\u0441\\u0442\\u0443\\u043f\\u0435\\u043d\\u0456\\u0432  \\u2116 15 \\u041c\\u041c\\u0420 \\u0417\\u041e  \\\" \\n                        height=\\\"20\\\" width=\\\"20\\\" \\/><\\/a> \\n                    <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id6523385\\\" \\n                       title=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0442\\u043e\\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430 \\u0417\\u041e\\u0428 I-III \\u0441\\u0442\\u0443\\u043f\\u0435\\u043d\\u0456\\u0432  \\u2116 15 \\u041c\\u041c\\u0420 \\u0417\\u041e  \\\">\\n                          <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id6523385\\\">\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0442\\u043e\\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430 \\u0417\\u041e\\u0428 I-III \\u0441\\u0442\\u0443\\u043f\\u0435\\u043d\\u0456\\u0432  \\u2116 15 \\u041c\\u041c\\u0420 \\u0417\\u041e  <\\/a><\\/a>\\n            <\\/div>\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-date\\\">\\u0441\\u0435\\u0433\\u043e\\u0434\\u043d\\u044f \\u0432 9:09<\\/div>\\n        <\\/div>\\n\\n                        <div class=\\\"ml-message\\\">\\n                    \\u0412\\u044b \\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u0443\\u0447\\u0438\\u043b\\u0438 \\u043e\\u0446\\u0435\\u043d\\u043a\\u0443 8 \\u043f\\u043e \\u043f\\u0440\\u0435\\u0434\\u043c\\u0435\\u0442\\u0443: \\u0406\\u0441\\u0442\\u043e\\u0440\\u0456\\u044f \\u0423\\u043a\\u0440\\u0430\\u0457\\u043d\\u0438, \\u041f\\u043e\\u0442\\u043e\\u0447\\u043d\\u0430                <\\/div>\\n                    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        <div class=\\\"clear\\\">\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-author\\\"><a \\n                    href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id3439774\\\" \\n                    title=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a \\u042e\\u043b\\u0456\\u044f \\u041b\\u0435\\u043e\\u043d\\u0456\\u0434\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\" class=\\\"mla-image\\\"><img \\n                        src=\\\"\\/users_img\\/users\\/avatars\\/343\\/3439774\\/20x20.jpg\\\" \\n                        alt=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a \\u042e\\u043b\\u0456\\u044f \\u041b\\u0435\\u043e\\u043d\\u0456\\u0434\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\" \\n                        height=\\\"20\\\" width=\\\"20\\\" \\/><\\/a> \\n                    <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id3439774\\\" \\n                       title=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a \\u042e\\u043b\\u0456\\u044f \\u041b\\u0435\\u043e\\u043d\\u0456\\u0434\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\">\\n                          <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id3439774\\\">\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a \\u042e\\u043b\\u0456\\u044f \\u041b\\u0435\\u043e\\u043d\\u0456\\u0434\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430<\\/a><\\/a>\\n            <\\/div>\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-date\\\"> 1 \\u0434.  \\u043d\\u0430\\u0437\\u0430\\u0434<\\/div>\\n        <\\/div>\\n\\n                        <div class=\\\"ml-message\\\">\\n                    \\u0412\\u044b\\u0434\\u0430\\u043d\\u043e \\u0434\\u0438\\u0441\\u0442\\u0430\\u043d\\u0446\\u0438\\u043e\\u043d\\u043d\\u043e\\u0435 \\u0437\\u0430\\u0434\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435 \\u043f\\u043e \\u043f\\u0440\\u0435\\u0434\\u043c\\u0435\\u0442\\u0443: \\u0423\\u043a\\u0440\\u0430\\u0457\\u043d\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430  \\u043b\\u0456\\u0442\\u0435\\u0440\\u0430\\u0442\\u0443\\u0440\\u0430                <\\/div>\\n                    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        <div class=\\\"clear\\\">\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-author\\\"><a \\n                    href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id6523385\\\" \\n                    title=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0442\\u043e\\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430 \\u0417\\u041e\\u0428 I-III \\u0441\\u0442\\u0443\\u043f\\u0435\\u043d\\u0456\\u0432  \\u2116 15 \\u041c\\u041c\\u0420 \\u0417\\u041e  \\\" class=\\\"mla-image\\\"><img \\n                        src=\\\"\\/images\\/no_picture.png\\\" \\n                        alt=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0442\\u043e\\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430 \\u0417\\u041e\\u0428 I-III \\u0441\\u0442\\u0443\\u043f\\u0435\\u043d\\u0456\\u0432  \\u2116 15 \\u041c\\u041c\\u0420 \\u0417\\u041e  \\\" \\n                        height=\\\"20\\\" width=\\\"20\\\" \\/><\\/a> \\n                    <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id6523385\\\" \\n                       title=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0442\\u043e\\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430 \\u0417\\u041e\\u0428 I-III \\u0441\\u0442\\u0443\\u043f\\u0435\\u043d\\u0456\\u0432  \\u2116 15 \\u041c\\u041c\\u0420 \\u0417\\u041e  \\\">\\n                          <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id6523385\\\">\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0442\\u043e\\u043f\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430 \\u0417\\u041e\\u0428 I-III \\u0441\\u0442\\u0443\\u043f\\u0435\\u043d\\u0456\\u0432  \\u2116 15 \\u041c\\u041c\\u0420 \\u0417\\u041e  <\\/a><\\/a>\\n            <\\/div>\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-date\\\"> 1 \\u0434.  \\u043d\\u0430\\u0437\\u0430\\u0434<\\/div>\\n        <\\/div>\\n\\n                        <div class=\\\"ml-message\\\">\\n                    \\u0412\\u044b\\u0434\\u0430\\u043d\\u043e \\u0434\\u0438\\u0441\\u0442\\u0430\\u043d\\u0446\\u0438\\u043e\\u043d\\u043d\\u043e\\u0435 \\u0437\\u0430\\u0434\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435 \\u043f\\u043e \\u043f\\u0440\\u0435\\u0434\\u043c\\u0435\\u0442\\u0443: \\u0406\\u0441\\u0442\\u043e\\u0440\\u0456\\u044f \\u0423\\u043a\\u0440\\u0430\\u0457\\u043d\\u0438                <\\/div>\\n                    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        <div class=\\\"clear\\\">\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-author\\\"><a \\n                    href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id1536524\\\" \\n                    title=\\\"\\u041a\\u0443\\u0440\\u0442\\u0432\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0454\\u0432\\u0430 \\u041e\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u0430 \\u041c\\u0438\\u043a\\u043e\\u043b\\u0430\\u0457\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\" class=\\\"mla-image\\\"><img \\n                        src=\\\"\\/images\\/no_avatar\\/woman.jpg\\\" \\n                        alt=\\\"\\u041a\\u0443\\u0440\\u0442\\u0432\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0454\\u0432\\u0430 \\u041e\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u0430 \\u041c\\u0438\\u043a\\u043e\\u043b\\u0430\\u0457\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\" \\n                        height=\\\"20\\\" width=\\\"20\\\" \\/><\\/a> \\n                    <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id1536524\\\" \\n                       title=\\\"\\u041a\\u0443\\u0440\\u0442\\u0432\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0454\\u0432\\u0430 \\u041e\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u0430 \\u041c\\u0438\\u043a\\u043e\\u043b\\u0430\\u0457\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\">\\n                          <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id1536524\\\">\\u041a\\u0443\\u0440\\u0442\\u0432\\u0435\\u043b\\u0456\\u0454\\u0432\\u0430 \\u041e\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u0430 \\u041c\\u0438\\u043a\\u043e\\u043b\\u0430\\u0457\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430<\\/a><\\/a>\\n            <\\/div>\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-date\\\"> 1 \\u0434.  \\u043d\\u0430\\u0437\\u0430\\u0434<\\/div>\\n        <\\/div>\\n\\n                        <div class=\\\"ml-message\\\">\\n                    \\u0412\\u044b\\u0434\\u0430\\u043d\\u043e \\u0434\\u0438\\u0441\\u0442\\u0430\\u043d\\u0446\\u0438\\u043e\\u043d\\u043d\\u043e\\u0435 \\u0437\\u0430\\u0434\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435 \\u043f\\u043e \\u043f\\u0440\\u0435\\u0434\\u043c\\u0435\\u0442\\u0443: \\u043c\\u0438\\u0441\\u0442\\u0435\\u0446\\u0442\\u0432\\u043e                <\\/div>\\n                    <\\/li>\\n    <li>\\n        <div class=\\\"clear\\\">\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-author\\\"><a \\n                    href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id3439774\\\" \\n                    title=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a \\u042e\\u043b\\u0456\\u044f \\u041b\\u0435\\u043e\\u043d\\u0456\\u0434\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\" class=\\\"mla-image\\\"><img \\n                        src=\\\"\\/users_img\\/users\\/avatars\\/343\\/3439774\\/20x20.jpg\\\" \\n                        alt=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a \\u042e\\u043b\\u0456\\u044f \\u041b\\u0435\\u043e\\u043d\\u0456\\u0434\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\" \\n                        height=\\\"20\\\" width=\\\"20\\\" \\/><\\/a> \\n                    <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id3439774\\\" \\n                       title=\\\"\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a \\u042e\\u043b\\u0456\\u044f \\u041b\\u0435\\u043e\\u043d\\u0456\\u0434\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\\\">\\n                          <a href=\\\"\\/ru\\/id3439774\\\">\\u041c\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a \\u042e\\u043b\\u0456\\u044f \\u041b\\u0435\\u043e\\u043d\\u0456\\u0434\\u0456\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430<\\/a><\\/a>\\n            <\\/div>\\n            <div class=\\\"ml-date\\\"> 1 \\u0434.  \\u043d\\u0430\\u0437\\u0430\\u0434<\\/div>\\n        <\\/div>\\n\\n                        <div class=\\\"ml-message\\\">\\n                    \\u0412\\u044b\\u0434\\u0430\\u043d\\u043e \\u0434\\u0438\\u0441\\u0442\\u0430\\u043d\\u0446\\u0438\\u043e\\u043d\\u043d\\u043e\\u0435 \\u0437\\u0430\\u0434\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435 \\u043f\\u043e \\u043f\\u0440\\u0435\\u0434\\u043c\\u0435\\u0442\\u0443: \\u0423\\u043a\\u0440\\u0430\\u0457\\u043d\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0430 \\u043c\\u043e\\u0432\\u0430                 <\\/div>\\n                    <\\/li>\\n\"}"
```

Гугл также его автоматически не парсит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122562/discussion-on-question-by-kuzcode-------json-c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, у нас входящая строка есть JSON-представление некоторого объекта, закодированное ещё раз по правилам JS.

Чтобы «снять» кодирование верхнего уровня, можно применить `JToken.Parse`:

```cs
var jsonString = (string)JToken.Parse(content);
```

Далее JSON разбираем стандартным образом:

```cs
var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

Итого:

```cs
var obj = JObject.Parse((string)JToken.Parse(content));
```

Answer (score 1):

Финальный рабочий код:

```
content = Regex.Unescape(content);
content = content.Remove(0, 1); // удаляем кавычку в начале
content = content.Remove(content.Length - 1, 1); // удаляем кавычку в конце
var json = JObject.Parse(content);
```

Comment: `var json = JObject.Parse(Regex.Unescape(content).Trim('"'));`

Comment: А почему не так: `JObject.Parse((string)JToken.Parse(content))`? Всё же у вас экранирование по правилам JS, а не по правилам .NET Regex, так что и разэкранировать нужно по этим же правилам.

Comment: @VladD да, вы правы, это лучший вариант